# websocket backend

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

Не понимаю возможно ли вообще сделать на php\js так, чтобы была какая-то функция, постоянно выполняющаяся на бэке, которая подключена к сокету и работает с данными. Все что нахожу, это как подключиться непосредственно на фронте. А мне это не нужно совершенно. Есть ли какие либо материалы, библиотеки?

Comment: да вроде есть https://habr.com/ru/post/209864/

Comment: Не сочтите за рекламу, но делаю ссыль на свои труды https://habr.com/ru/post/311986/